# Symfony: un-secure a backend module for certain kinds of users. How?

Tags: php, security, symfony1, propel

Straight to the point -- I have a Symfony 1.3 / Propel 1.4 project. I have a module which is secured via `is_secure: true` in its own `security.yml`. I want this module to be accessible not only for super admins -- I am using the `sfGuardPlugin` symfony plugin. The module is located in the `backend` app.

I would like to make the module accessible to users who have any value of their `type` property. Regular users of the site have `NULL` in there, all of the rest have a value of some kind. When I change the security directive to `is_secure: false` (just to test it), I then go to `/admin` and do login with a user who has some `type`, I get properly redirected to `/admin/purchases` (the only non-secured `backend` module) but with security error message -- "You do not have access to show this page" or something along the lines.

Since I am not quite so familiar with `sfGuardPlugin` (and Symfony's security in general), I would like some help as to how do I do this, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_action_security) about action security.

Use group permissions from sfGuardPlugin to automatically ad credentials for users of your choice (see [extra documentation](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/sfGuardPluginExtraDocumentation#sfGuardSecurityUserclass) for sfGuardPlugin in order to understand how the plugin converts user groups and permissions into credentials)

Comment: I will surely take a look, but since I am still a rookie at Symfony, I would be grateful if you could sketch me some pseudo-code and which files to touch. You know, makes somebody new much more confident when he has an example code to meddle with. ;)

Comment: Reviewed the doc, but unfortunately at the moment it doesn't cover my scenario, which is: I already have a `backend` module named `purchase` (it is generated via the Symfony's admin generators), and I just want to filter out this particular module (or some of its actions) from the admin-level security. The documentation you linked (the first link) doesn't cover the `backend` module case. :-(

Comment: OK, it is sorted. Too lazy to share step by step process, but I did it. The linked documentation helped after all. Marking this.

Comment: `backend` is just an app like `frontend` or any other app, so it should be simple. As for example code i don't know what to say. I thought everything will be done through GUI of `sfGuardPlugin`, just add one line with credentials name to the apropriate `security.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to relay on the security.yml credentials, you could also handle this inside an action:

```
public function executeIndex($request){
  if(!$this->getUser()->hasGroup('desired-group')){
    $this->getUser->setFlash('message', 'You do not have access to show this page');
    return $this->redirect('admin/purchases');
  }

  // more logic here
}
```

If this works for more actions of your module, yould could use the preExecute() methode in case of DRY (dont repeat yourself…)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you've got the right credentials for each user. In your backend modules 
security.yml file you can do this:

```
all:
  credentials: [[admin, developer]]
```

Or you can do individual actions:

```
requestView:
  credentials: [[supporter, admin, developer]]
```